# Filling form with editable value - php and html

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have read a lot of question here but I couldn't get anything to work. I have such a instructions:

```
$query = "SELECT nazwa,rok_prod,wypornosc FROM statek where id_statek=$id";
$wynik = pg_query($query);
$liczba_kolumn = pg_num_fields($wynik);
echo "<form action=edos.php method=post>";
echo "<table border width=1>";
for($k = 0;$k<$liczba_kolumn; $k++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo pg_field_name($wynik,$k);
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<input type=text name=".pg_field_name($wynik,$k) "value=".pg_fetch_result($wynik,0,$k).">";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

And I want to display values from SELECT in fields, that I could change it later - it is for editing form. I have tried in a lot of ways:

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($name);?>" />
```

but nothing is working. I have tested `pg_fetch_result($wynik,0,$k)` and there is what I want but how to display it and make it editable?

Comment: What **does** your output/result look like? Also, this is obviously wrong: `echo "<input type=text name=".pg_field_name($wynik,$k) "value=".pg_fetch_result($wynik,0,$k).">";` as there are no quotes around the attribute values (which is also the case in line 4 and 5). Plus you're forgetting the dot after the first function call.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the dot, I have corrected it. My output looks in this way: [link](http://4.1m.yt/SiHG5-JHs.jpg). I can fill it but I want to be there my value from select. I have to put text in quotes like this `echo "<input type="text" name=".pg_field_name($wynik,$k)."value=". pg_fetch_result($wynik,0,$k).">";` ? If yes I get an error: [link](http://4.1m.yt/NJEB8ccwS.jpg)

Comment: You get that error because a string in double quotes can not simply contain the double quote character, as it ends the string. You either need to use single quotes or escape the double quotes: `echo "He said \"It works!\"";` - and for your problem, you should check what your functions are actually returning; looks like they're not returning anything, hence nothing is being displayed.

Comment: Hmm. If i will add something like that `$war = pg_fetch_result($wynik,0,$k);' and 'echo $war;' in the same column i have a field to enter text and my result from $war (of course it is in loop). It is not empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I recommend you to read about [PHP Strings](https://php.net/language.types.string), especially the difference between single and double quoted strings and how to escape characters.

Second, you're forgetting to add the double quotes around the HTML attribute values, forgot a dot and am missing a space. This line:

```
echo "<input type=text name=".pg_field_name($wynik,$k) "value=".pg_fetch_result($wynik,0,$k).">";
```

Would output something like `<input type=text name=foovalue=bar>`, assuming that your first function call will return `foo` and the second returns `bar`.

What you need is, for example:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"".pg_field_name($wynik,$k)."\" value=\"".pg_fetch_result($wynik,0,$k)."\">";
```

Which should output `<input type="text" name="foo" value="bar">`

As this tends to get messy and is therefore error-prone, I would recommend you to look into parsing strings with functions like [printf](http://php.net/printf).

Apart from that, I am guessing that your functions `pf_fetch_name` and `pg_fetch_result` are not returning anything (or an empty string), and therefore you get empty input fields. Hence, the error might lie within these function and/or the SQL queries they are (probably?) carrying out. This is what you should look into.

**Edit**:

To get things a bit tidier, I would further recommend to avoid all the `echo`s. This can be done by simply having the actual HTML markup outside of the `<?php ?>` tags and then injecting your values with the shorthand tags `<?= ?>`. A shortened example:

```
<?php
// Some PHP code
for ($i = 1; $i <= $something; ++$i) {
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?= fetch_foo(); ?></td>
        <td><?= fetch_bar(); ?></td>
    </tr>
<table>
<?php
} // closing the for loop
?>
```

Comment: Cool, glad it works! I'll add a bit more info to my answer still that should help you to tidy up your code a bit.